# Php route parser end of the URL

Tags: php, router

I wrote a little php url parser for my own php-mvc-framework and i need little help in the following code:

```
<?php
class Route{

private $routes = [];

public function __construct(){}

public function addRoute($method, $url, $callback){
    $this->routes[] = array('method' => $method, 
                          'url' => $url, 
                          'callback' => $callback);
}

public function doRouting(){
    $reqUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $reqMet = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    foreach($this->routes as  $route) {

        // convert urls like '/users/:uid/posts/:pid' to regular expression      
        $pattern = "@^" . preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($route['url'])) . "$@D";
        $matches = array();

        if($reqMet == $route['method'] && preg_match($pattern, $reqUrl, $matches)) {

            // remove the first match
            array_shift($matches);
            // call the callback with the matched positions as params
            return call_user_func_array($route['callback'], $matches);
        }
    }
}

$route = new Route();

$route->addRoute('GET', '/', function(){
     echo 'root';
});

 $route->addRoute('GET', '/users/', function(){
     echo 'users';
 });
 $route->addRoute('GET', '/users/:uid/posts/:pid/', function($uid, $pid){
     echo $uid.'<br/>'.$pid;
 });

 $route->addRoute('GET', '/users/:uid/posts/:pid/edit', function($uid, $pid){
     echo 'users posts edit';
 });


 $route->doRouting();
```

I want allow an optional `/` at the end of the URL. For example, in this current routes definition when `REQUEST_URI` is `/users/123/posts/456` i want same result(function call) when `REQUEST_URI` is `/users/123/posts/456/`.

Also, `/users/123/posts/456/edit` call new function.

Comment: There's a very nice router here, if you ever decide that renventing the wheel isn't a good idea after all: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/routing

Comment: Ok, it's very nice (and big), but i want solve exact problem in my part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip trailing slashes from your route if needed:

```
$route['url'] = rtrim($route['url'], '/');
```

And then terminate your route's pattern accordingly:

```
$pattern = preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($route['url'], '@'));
$pattern = "@^$pattern/?$@D";
```

Comment: This not working, problem is preg_replace 4th param(must be long), and every route point to root url.

Comment: Fixed the typos... Your original preg_quote doesn't escape patterns with an @.

Comment: Yes, but with this solution, $route->addRoute('GET', '/', callback) not working for homepage. Second param must be '', but this is is not very user friendly definition. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I also add $route['url'] = rtrim($route['url'], '/'); in foreach loop and then everything is working as expected! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

You could just `rtrim` the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` before doing the routing:

```
$reqUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$reqUrl = rtrim($reqUrl, '/');
```

But in doing so don't add the slash to the route definitions:

```
$route->addRoute('GET', '', ...
$route->addRoute('GET', '/users/:uid/posts/:pid', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

place this code in your current code where you validate your URL

```
$url="some/url/";
$slash=substr($url, -1); // returns "/"
//remove the '/' from end of the url
if($slash=="/") {
trim($slash, "/"); //many alternatives can be used for this function
}
```

Above code, it will check your url and will remove the '/' if it is in the url, so basically it will do the same thing as a url without a slash in the end.
Hope that helps